# Unity HeidiSQL Connection timed out

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mariadb, heidisql

In my Unity project i have a MariaDB and HeidiSQL as the interface. I now want to connect my unity script with that database and make queries.
In my `Database.cs` i have following code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public class Database : MonoBehaviour
{
    private MySqlConnection connection;
    private string server;
    private string database;
    private string user;
    private string password;

    public void Database_Initialize()
    {
        server = "IP-ADDRESS";
        database = "DB_NAME";
        user = "USERNAME";
        password = "PASSWORD";

        string connectionString = "Server=IP-ADDRESS;Port=PORT;Database=DB_NAME;Uid=USERNAME;Pwd=PASSWORD;";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        connection.Open();

        string query = "INSERT INTO user (UserName) VALUES ('User1')";
        MySqlCommand command = new(query, connection);

        command.CommandTimeout = 60;

        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Access data using reader["columnname"]
        }
        reader.Close();

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

when i run this script i get following error:
`TimeoutException: The operation has timed out. Rethrow as MySqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetTcpStream (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream& networkStream) (at <13314bc2115d4bd2a5d896df29fb7179>:0)`

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

P.S. the MySQL.Data.dll file is from here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: Did you mean to use the server, database, user and password variables? Because you use hardcoded values instead. Anyway, there is no ExecuteReader for an INSERT, you should use ExecuteNonQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear whether you want to insert a user into the database, read something from the database or both, I'm assuming insert.
The changes are described in the comments.

```cs
public void Database_Initialize()
{
    server = "IP-ADDRESS";
    database = "DB_NAME";
    user = "USERNAME";
    password = "PASSWORD";

    // Use interpolated strings to insert the values from variables
    string connectionString = $"Server={server};Port=PORT;Database={database};Uid={user};Pwd={password};";
    // Use "using" pattern to make sure everything is disposed
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        string query = "INSERT INTO user (UserName) VALUES ('User1')";
        using (MySqlCommand command = new(query, connection))
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = 60;
            // Use ExecuteNonQuery to execute the INSERT.
            // recordsChanged should be 1 afterwards
            int recordsChanged = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```